# Do I need to await my async function, then return?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have two functions.

1.

```
async function firstFunction() {
  // Do stuff here
  // I can't just return doSomeOtherThings because the firstFunction
  // returns different data then what doSomeOtherThings does
  doSomeOtherThings();
  return;
}
```

2. 

```
async function doSomeOtherThings() {
  // do promise stuff here
  // this function runs some db operations
}
```

If I run `firstFunction();` will it execute my `doSomeOtherThings()` function, or will it return early from that and cause some or all of the doSomeOtherThings code to not be executed? Do I need to do `await doSomeOtherThings()`?

Comment: It will be executed, but not awaited...

Comment: Did you check it in the console log?

Comment: I did check the console and yes, it does seem to be executing, but I didn't know if that was just a race condition and once the code is in production if it would stop execution. I guess I don't deeply understand how the operations are being executed here.

Comment: @FZs so all of the code in updateOtherThing should run eventually?

Comment: Yes. You've called it, so it will run. However, even if you don't await it, remember to handle its promise, so that errors don't go unnoticed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a bit of confusion here, so I'll try to start from the beggining.

First, async functions always return a promise. If you add another async function inside that, you COULD chain them and wait for a response before returning the first promise. However, if you dont await the inner function, the first function will be resolved while the second is still running.

```
async function firstFunction() {
  if (I want to wait for doSomeOtherThings to finished before ending firstFunction){
    await   doSomeOtherThings();
  } else if (I can finish firstFUnction and let doSomeOtherTHings finish later){
    doSomeOtherThings
  }

  return;
}

async function init() {
  const apiResponse = await firstFunction();
};

init();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One of these days I'll understand promises...I'm sure it will happen...one day. This helps

Comment: Glad to help, bud. Took me a while too. If you'll need any further clarification, I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have await. Actually 'async/await' is just a syntax sugar.
You function updateOtherThings actually returns a Promise, and if you don't await it, then it simply doesn't run.
If you want simply to start and forget it, then write something like:

```js
    updateOtherThings().then(() => {});
```